# Perfino Server start / stop

Tags: perfino

Regarding Perfino from EJ-Technologies...:

On a Windows Server 2008 R2 platform, does Perfino Server install as a Windows Service or as a webserver with bin/startup and bin/shutdown adminstration?

Comment: Consider posting this question on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It installs as a windows service. You can also disable the service and start it on the terminal with `bin\perfino_console.exe`.